# Cannot upload mp3 using C#, please help!

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? I'm trying to upload a mp3 with this piece of code and when i try to do so i get a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="upload" runat="server" Text="GO" OnClick="btn_Click" /><br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<script runat="server">
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileExt =
           System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

        if (fileExt == ".mp3")
        {
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" +
                   FileUpload1.FileName));
                Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                    "Content type: " +
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Only .mp3 files allowed!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
}



    </script>
```

Comment: Does it work with any other file (maybe a small mp3 file)?  Have you tried changing a text file's extension to .mp3 and uploading it just to see if it would work with te very small size?

Comment: I tried removing the extension part and it does work. I haven't try a small mp3 yet! Do you think the size matters?

Comment: in this case it does matter :). By default its 4 mb.

Comment: The default size is 4mb if I remember correctly ...anyway you can change it <system.web>
  <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>

Comment: can i remove this size limit? Is there any way around this?

Comment: @jorame it can matter, since there is a maximum post data size limit: see [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx), under memory limitations for more info.

Comment: It's amazing things you can forget when working under pressure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increase the http maxRequestLength using following in your web.config - it should work then. By default it's limited at 4mb.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```